# Yii2: как добавить в SearchModel массив значений?

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Делаю выборку данных из базы. Необходимо выбрать все товары, входящие в текущую категорию, а также в её подкатегории. Сделать это без датапровайдера просто, если в моделях прописаны связи. Но вот очень хочется использовать датапровайдер.

В Yii2 для выборки данных используется такой код:

```
$searchModel = new FooSearch;
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams());
```

Однако к передаваемым GET'ом параметрам нужно добавить параметры по умолчанию (в моем случае — id категорий). Если параметр один, то [это можно сделать так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031644/yii2-how-to-add-fixed-filter-in-serachmodel-search):

```
$searchModel = new FooSearch;
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(ArrayHelper::merge(
    Yii::$app->request->queryParams,
    [$searchModel->formName() => ['id_bar' => $id]]
));
```

Или [так](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/663/yii2-default-values-for-index-data-provider/).

Но вот как передать не *один* параметр, а *массив*?

Answer (score 2):

Можно собрать список подкатегорий в строку при помощи *implode* и передать в *SearchModel* как это указано выше в вопросе.

А собственно в соответствующую *SearchModel* нужно внести пару изменений:

1. Перенести в методе *rules()* **id** категории из *integer* в *safe* (передается-то теперь не число, а строка).
2. Вынести фильтр в методе search() в отдельный блок. Было:

   ```
   $query->andFilterWhere([
       'id_category' => $this->id_category,
   ]);
   ```

   стало:

   ```
   $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'id_category', explode(',', $this->id_category)]);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Небольшая корректировка предыдущего комментария. Если необходимо передать в SearchModel Yii2 именно массив значений вида $params[], то в п.2 меняем query-запрос на запрос следующего вида:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'id_category', $this->id_category]);
```

Comment: Это нужно было оформить в качестве комментария к предыдущему ответу, раз это его корректировка